# MySQL table display empty value after insert data into it by using AngularJS and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, http-post

I'm a AngularJS and PHP newbie and I'm trying to add some data into MySQL. But MySQL table shows empty value instead of the data I want to insert.

HTML:

```
<form data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
     <label for="roomName">Room Name: </label>
     <input type="text" name="roomName" data-ng-model="roomName" id="roomName" />

     <br />

     <label for="maxPerson">Maximum Person: </label>
     <input type="text" name="maxPerson" data-ng-model="maxPerson" id="maxPerson" />
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="addRoom()">Add</button>
</form>
```

app.js (Controller)

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
     "use strict";

     $scope.addRoom = function () {
         $http.post("add_library_room.php", {'roomName': $scope.roomName, 'maxPax': $scope.maxPerson})
             .then(function (response) {
                 $scope.msg = "Room is inserted into database.";
             });
     };
});
```

add_library_room.php (Insert data)

```
<?php

define("HOSTNAME","localhost");
define("USERNAME","root");
define("PASSWORD","");
define("DATABASE", "booking_db");

$dbhandle=new mysqli(HOSTNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE) or die ("Unable to Connect to the Database");

$data=json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$room_Name=$dbhandle->real_escape_string($data->roomName);
$max_Pax=$dbhandle->real_escape_string($data->maxPax);

$query="INSERT INTO library_discussion_room (room_name, max_pax) VALUES ('$room_Name', '$max_Pax')";

$dbhandle->query($query);

?>
```

phpMyAdmin MySQL database (The value that I had inserted is empty):
[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V46Ze.png)

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Hope you guys can help me to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Does it show your success message about posting datas to php file?
For me it looks like you are not even sending correct datas from angular.
(At least in Ionic fw i'm using the {key: value} syntax instead of {"key":value}, but maybe it doesn't matter, just a tip).
Try to print your $data array.

Comment: I can get my success message. But it looks like the data is empty.

Comment: print_r your $data variable, and then console.log the 'response' parameter.

Comment: The message below is displayed in console:

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$room_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\BookingSystem\add_library_room.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$max_pax in C:\xampp\htdocs\BookingSystem\add_library_room.php on line 9
stdClass Object ( )

Comment: I still think, that you are passing empty properties to your php file.

Comment: So any solution on how to pass the value from ng-model to php?

Comment: First, try to log/alert the values of your ngModels. If it logs/alerts it correctly, then the issue will be in your backend (php), if it is undefined, then try to attach your ng-model value to an object, so that the ng-model will have at least one dot in its value. e.g.:
`ng-model="room.roomName"` and in the controller, you create an empty object called room. e.g: `var room = {};` and ofcourse refer to your object's properties in the `$http.post` method.

Comment: Wow. It works for me.
Thank you for your help. :)
But why I need to create an object instead of using "ng-model="roomName"?

Comment: I'll explain it in an answer, so you can mark it as a solution. [Point hunter, lol] :D

Comment: Alright. I'll mark it later. Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are directly trying to write the data on the scope.
Angular JS often creates childscopes inside of directives to avoid messing up with higher level datas.
So if you directly write `ng-model="something"`, then it will become only a distinct, and not a reference.

In order to make it work, you'll need to make an object, and refer to it's properties, since angular will search for that object in parent scopes too.

So the solution will be sth like this:

```
ng-model="object.property"
```

and then in your controller

```
$scope.object = {};
$scope.addRoom = function () {
     $http.post("add_library_room.php", {'roomName': $scope.object.roomName, 'maxPax': $scope.object.maxPerson})
         .then(function (response) {
             $scope.msg = "Room is inserted into database.";
         });
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure instead of using

```
$data=json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

you cannot simple use

```
$data=$_POST;
```

Just print your $data variable by doing a

```
print_r($data);
```

You must be getting $data as empty.

Comment: So how am I going to get the data and insert into mysql table?
I'm still new in AngularJS and PHP.

Comment: Instead of using 
$data=json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
try 
$data=$_POST;
and then do 
print_r($data);
to check if the data was assigned to the $data variable.
  You might need to check the Network tab of your Browser debugger to see the output for this

Comment: I get this error message:

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\BookingSystem\add_library_room.php on line 8

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\BookingSystem\add_library_room.php on line 9

Fatal error: Call to undefined function print_f() in C:\xampp\htdocs\BookingSystem\add_library_room.php on line 16

Comment: Correct the function name to print_r

Comment: After I corrected to print_r, these 2 error messages still exist.

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\BookingSystem\add_library_room.php on line 8

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\BookingSystem\add_library_room.php on line 9
Array ( )